# jquery slide down effect

Tags: jquery

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/X9Vn4/50/) is the slide down effect and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brightonmike/X9Vn4/54/) is the same code but with fadeIn() and the div inside it is not working when I use the fadeIn.

To see what I'm talking about check this [link](http://outboxvision.com/gallery2/)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry,I've edited my post now

Comment: Alecs, external links to your code do not count toward a complete and useful question. Please copy and paste your code into questions, even with the (much appreciated, mind you!) external resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.hover()` takes two arguments. What do do on `mouseenter` and what to do on `mouseleave`. Make sure you're putting both functions in as arguments if you're going to use hover.